# iterating through list with floor loop jinja django python

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I have this array:
scores = [45.62, 51.87, 33.12, 39.37, 33.12]

I want to iterate through the list, and pass each item to an html template.

Using jinga, i tried the following:

```
{% for items in scores %}
    {‌{ items }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

I hoped that the above would print out each item in the list like so: 
45.62 
51.87 
33.12 
etc...

but it didn't, it just prints the entire list, as a list, on one line.

I also tried this:

```
{% for items in scores %}
    {‌{ scores.0 }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

This printed out just the first score of the list, but not the others. I want to print out each score individually. Please help! I'm using django 1.9. I know this is jinja, not sure if it's jinja2?

Comment: so you are using jinja in django templates, right?

Comment: your first version should work.

Comment: I thought the same but it doesn't... I'm perplexed as to why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feels like list is not as you put in question.Try this

```
{% for items in scores.0 %}
    {‌{ items }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing up the variable names. Maybe you have another variable called `items` in your context. It would make more sense to use a variable name that's not plural for the loop.

```
{% for score in scores %}
    {‌{ score }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```